# How to replace first and last character of column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a  database column and its give a string like `,Recovery, Pump Exchange,`.

I want remove first and last comma from string.

Expected Result : `Recovery, Pump Exchange`.

Comment: if first and last comma is not exist in string then as it is result come.

Comment: Comma separated lists present an entire host of issues when stored within a single database column.  It is *MUCH BETTER* in the long run to store each of these values as a distinct row.  SO is filled with the same repetitive questions about how to work with and manipulate poorly designed columns like this.  I feel bad if this is out of your control, but your are attempting to fix an issue, why not go all the way and create a new child table with each value split out?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) for that:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, 2, LEN(col)-2)
FROM ...
```

Obviously, an even better approach would be not to put leading and trailing commas there in the first place, if this is an option.

> I want to remove last and first comma only if exist otherwise not.

The expression becomes a little more complex, but the idea remains the same:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    col
,  CASE LEFT(@col,1) WHEN ',' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
,  LEN(@col) -- Start with the full length
             -- Subtract 1 for comma on the left
      - CASE LEFT(@col,1) WHEN ',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
             -- Subtract 1 for comma on the right
      - CASE RIGHT(@col,1) WHEN ',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
FROM ...
```

Comment: i want only remove last and first comma only if exist other wise not.

Comment: @ManishSharma:- Then you may like to check bendataclear answer!

Comment: ya sorry for that but i have used this.bu data is not coming properly so i would like to post that comment below my question.

Comment: @ManishSharma:- Updated my answer with the condition. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great this post is very useful for all developer.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to dasblinkenlight's method you could use replace:

```
DECLARE @words VARCHAR(50) = ',Recovery, Pump Exchange,'
SELECT REPLACE(','+ @words + ',',',,','')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using LEN could backfire because LEN ignores trailing spaces. These could be added because of ANSI_PADDING defaulting to ON. So, you'd need RTRIM.

For completeness, I've added LTRIM too...

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyCol, 2, 8000)))), 2, 8000))
```

Answer (score 3):

For removing same character you can use below system function [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Only from **`2017`**

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '[REMOVE THIS CLOSE BRACKET]'

SELECT TRIM('[]' FROM @str)
```

But for different character removing you need to use SUBSTRING

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,2,LEN(@str)-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Substring()`:

```
SET @String=SUBSTRING(@String ,2,Len(@String)-2)
```

`SUBSTRING()` returns part of an expression.

Syntax:

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if(Substring(@mykeyword, 1,1) = ',' and Substring(@mykeyword, LEN(@mykeyword) - 1, LEN(@mykeyword))=',')
SET @mykeyword = Substring(@mykeyword, 2, LEN(@mykeyword) - 2)
```

Comment: but how can i use this in SQL quesry please provide proper query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(',Recovery, Pump Exchange,',LEN(',Recovery, Pump Exchange,')-1),LEN(',Recovery, Pump Exchange,')-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I've decided to add my solution as it will remove the first and last commas of a comma separated string without removing the other commas and also will work with strings that don't start with a comma:

```
DECLARE @words VARCHAR(50) = ',Recovery, Pump Exchange,'
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@words , 1, 1),',','') + SUBSTRING(@words, 2, LEN(@words)-2) + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@words, LEN(@words), 1), ',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to replace first and last character of column in table.

In this example, I have used double quotes(") instead of comma(,). It will replace only first and last character(“), if the column value starts with double quotes(“) and ended with double quotes(“).

```
DECLARE @tblProducts TABLE (ProductName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tblProducts VALUES ('"Recovery 10x12" Pump Exchange"')
INSERT INTO @tblProducts VALUES ('"Recovery Pump Exchange 10x12""')
INSERT INTO @tblProducts VALUES ('Recovery Pump Exchange 10x12"')

--REPLACE Last Char(")
UPDATE @tblProducts SET ProductName = SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, len(ProductName) - 1) FROM @tblProducts WHERE ProductName LIKE '"%' AND ProductName LIKE '%"'

--REPLACE First Char(")
UPDATE @tblProducts SET ProductName = SUBSTRING(ProductName, 2, len(ProductName) - 1) FROM @tblProducts WHERE ProductName LIKE '"%'

SELECT * FROM @tblProducts
```

Result:

[image]