# sql best way to get rid of leading and trailing characters in a varchar

Tags: sql, t-sql, varchar

I have a variable (a varchar) in my procedure that contains something like:

```
{A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C}
```

what should I do to have

```
A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C
```

(without the '{' and '}') instead?

Always same length and always leading and trailing character

Comment: Always same length? Always leading and trailing char?

Comment: yes, always same length and always leading and trailing char

Comment: The best way is to remove then before they get to the DB layer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352610/how-to-replace-first-and-last-character-of-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring is going to do this for you. The way this works is it takes the string starting from the 2nd character (excludes the first character) and uses the length of the string itself minus 2 to exclude the final character.

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData (StringValue nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES 
('{A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C}')

SELECT
    StringValue
    ,SUBSTRING(StringValue,2,LEN(StringValue)-2) NewValue
FROM #SampleData

DROP TABLE #SampleData
```

Results;

```
StringValue                             NewValue
{A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C}  A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@string, 2, LEN(@string) - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily so as follows:

```
declare @data varchar(100)
set @data='{A6DF61AB-8CBF-4E1C-890B-15A7710C7D9C}'
select replace(replace(@data,'{',''),'}','')
```